# Is there Goth Kids 2 episode of South Park?

Tags: identify-this-episode, south-park

Episode 17.4 of South Park is called "Goth Kids 3: Dawn of the Posers".
I would like to find episodes Goth Kids 1 and Goth Kids 2, but failing to do this. Are there such episodes at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [this Wikia page](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Goth_Kids_3:_Dawn_of_the_Posers) explains, this episode is a sequel to 2 other episodes where the Goths were featured most prominently: [Raisins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisins_%28South_Park%29) from season 7 (where Stan becomes a Goth) and [The Ungroundable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ungroundable) from season 12 (where Butters becomes a vampire wannabe). The title of this episode is probably a parody of *Ice Age 3: Dawn of the Dinosaurs* and maybe alludes to *Dawn of the Dead* (though that was the *2nd* film in Romero's zombie series).